# Replace all " and ' from a string

Tags: c#

I want to replace all the " and ' from a string

eg strings

```
"23423dfd
"'43535fdgd
""'4353fg
""'''3453ere
```

the result should be

```
23423dfd
43535fdgd
4353fg
3453ere
```

I tried this `myString.Replace("'",string.Empty).Replace('"',string.Empty);` but its not giving me the correct result.

Comment: Did you try [string.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) ?

Comment: @Habib: yes i tried, "\" is what i want

Comment: you should post what have you tried and where you are stuck at

Comment: @Habib: okay Habib, I will take care this in future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx)

```
mystring = mystring.Replace("\"", string.Empty).Replace("'", string.Empty)
```

Comment: If its useful, Please upvote question too.

Answer (score 1):

Do two replaces:

```
s = s.Replace("'", "").Replace("\"", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string s = yoursting.Replace("\"", string.Empty).Replace("'", string.Empty);
```